# autorelease deprecated, is there an alternative?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

Following a tutorial for a photo slideshow for code ivI'e run into what I think is some deprecated code. I have an ARC error at `autorelease` and a warning with the `setDelegate:self`

```
NSXMLParser *photoParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc]
                                 initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                        @"http://localhost/photos/index.xml"]] autorelease];
    [photoParser setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: It's not "deprecated" (meaning it won't be supported in the future). You just don't need to write it when using ARC (the compiler will put in `retain`, `release`, `autorelease`, etc where appropriate for you).

Answer (score 3):

Remove the autorelease so that the code looks like the following:

ARC does not allow explicit autorelease calls. If you want an object to be deallocated you don't have to do anything (ARC will handle it). In some case you may want to set an object to nil (such as photoParser = nil;)

```
NSXMLParser *photoParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]
                                 initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                        @"http://localhost/photos/index.xml"]];
[photoParser setDelegate:self];
```